# Encrypted external drive won't mount anymore

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, encryption, mount

I have a 1 TB external drive I use for Time Machine, and as manual backup external drive. It is encrypted.

I started to convert it back to normal. I was able to mount it correctly several times while the conversion was in progress, but now it is not working anymore. Can't be mounted.

```
diskutil corestorage list

CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 390B29FA-501C-4A34-BCE9-A2249F1FA2A3
    =========================================================
    Name:         HDEXT1TB
    Status:       Online
    Size:         999860912128 B (999.9 GB)
    Free Space:   5943296 B (5.9 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume FB6151D3-4BEA-4C69-A744-A17B9AE18262
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999860912128 B (999.9 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 21CF48F7-8D6D-4990-A2E6-C21680852F03
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Conversion Status:       Converting (backward)
        Reversion State:         Decrypting
        High Level Queries:      Not Fully Secure
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 45E49F43-C577-415F-B606-3295EB25FAB3
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk3
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          999502643200 B (999.5 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   57%
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               HDEXT1TB
            Volume Name:           HDEXT1TB
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFSX


diskutil mount readOnly 45E49F43-C577-415F-B606-3295EB25FAB3
disk3 is a CoreStorage Logical Volume which failed to mount

diskutil corestorage decryptvolume 45E49F43-C577-415F-B606-3295EB25FAB3
Started CoreStorage operation on disk3 HDEXT1TB
Error: -69649: This Core Storage logical volume is already decrypting
```

Is there any way to mount it again? It seems to be still decrypting, do you think I can simply leave it attached to the Mac even if not mounted?

Comment: Assuming conversion rate is 20 MB/s and making and drinking a coffee takes 5 minutes, drink another 71.6 cups. Then check back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution:

ps aux |grep disk3

this reported a fsck_hfs -y on disk 3, consuming either a lot of cpu as well as keeping the drive like as locked.

killed the related PID

then the disk mounted itself immediately. the conversion is still in progress, 60% now, but at least I can access files.

thanks.